# query in Realm database

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

Im using realm in my iOS application an i want to fire query on silent push notification, query string is given by push.
Is it possible to query realm database in single string? like SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use SQL queries, since Realm is a NoSQL database, but you can use NSPredicates to query it and you can generate an NSPredicate from a string.
Have a look at [Filtering in the official Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering)

Comment: can i query with single string?

Comment: And also i don't want to use sql query, i want like sql!

Comment: As I have already stated in my answer, you can use only use NSPredicates for queries, but you can generate an NSPredicate using a single string if the string is formatted using NSPredicate syntax.